# How to display raw messages in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Find sudo mit PPID 1
  hosts: solaris
  become: true

  tasks:
    - shell: "pgrep -P1 -x sudo | xargs -n1 ptree"
      register: result
    - debug: var=result.stdout_lines
```

The command `ansible-playbook` quotes the standard output of the command in JSON syntax:

```
ok: [gggggggg] => {
    "result.stdout_lines": [
        "26982 sudo su -", 
        "  26983 -sh", 
        "    6628  zlogin NNNNNNNN", 
        "      6629  -sh"
    ]
}
```

This is pretty unreadable for me.

Is it possible to write stdout without JSON quoting as it is done by ad-hoc commands?

```
gggggggg | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
17589 sudo su -
  17590 -sh
    17613 zlogin NNNNNNNN
      17614 -sh
        17646 bash
```

Comment: No, but you could instead write the output to a file.

Comment: @larsks Can I use file descriptor 2 as the file?

Comment: You can use `results.stdout`

Comment: @TimFletcher No I can't. It is even less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the to_nice_json filter:

```
tasks:
- shell: "pgrep -P1 -x sudo | xargs -n1 ptree"
  register: result
- debug: var="{{ result.stdout_lines | to_nice_json }}"
```